# Cut number from json and put to curl command

Tags: json, bash, curl, grep

I try create script to get index number from getsubtitlemenulist, after text "Inne","index":" so this is "21" and put to code below $NUMER. I cannot use jq, python on this machine so I need use command like grep, awk.

text from getsubtitlemenulist

```
{"success":true,"msg":"","file_path":"","subtitle_list":[{"name":"Wył.","index":0,"selected":false},{"name":"1/21 Duński","index":1,"selected":false},{"name":"2/21 Niemiecki","index":2,"selected":false},{"name":"3/21 Angielski","index":3,"selected":false},{"name":"4/21 Hiszpański","index":4,"selected":false},{"name":"5/21 Francuski","index":5,"selected":false},{"name":"6/21 Włoski","index":6,"selected":false},{"name":"7/21 Niderlandzki","index":7,"selected":false},{"name":"8/21 Norweski","index":8,"selected":false},{"name":"9/21 Fiński","index":9,"selected":false},{"name":"10/21 Szwecki","index":10,"selected":false},{"name":"11/21 Angielski","index":11,"selected":false},{"name":"12/21 Niemiecki","index":12,"selected":false},{"name":"13/21 Angielski","index":13,"selected":false},{"name":"14/21 Hiszpański","index":14,"selected":false},{"name":"15/21 Francuski","index":15,"selected":false},{"name":"16/21 Włoski","index":16,"selected":false},{"name":"17/21 Niemiecki","index":17,"selected":false},{"name":"18/21 Hiszpański","index":18,"selected":false},{"name":"19/21 Francuski","index":19,"selected":false},{"name":"20/21 Włoski","index":20,"selected":false},{"name":"Inne","index":21,"selected":true}]}
```

```
if curl "$ip/getsubtitlemenulist?" | ? xxxxxx ?

   curl "$ip/setsubttmenulist?%7B%22cur_index%22%3A$NUMER%7D"

fi
```

Comment: Our answers telling people how to use jq also tell people how to use Python from bash for JSON encoding; nice thing about Python is it's installed out-of-the-box on any modern distro.

Comment: This is embedded os on bly-ray player :) bin's are limited :)

Comment: Ahh. That might be a situation where a crude regex approach _could_ conceivably be adequate. There _are_ regex-based approaches on the linked duplicate, as failure-prone as they are.